# Yii2 - How to access cookies in configuration config/web.php

Tags: php, yii2

I want to create a light/dark toggle using botstrap action in my Yii2 basic project,
So, my pseudocode like this.

In before action all controller, I check if action request have cookies theme

```
    'on beforeAction' => function ($event) {

        // default theme is 'light'
        if(!Yii::$app->request->cookies->has('theme')){
            Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new Cookie([
                'name' => 'theme',
                'value' => 'light',
            ]));
        }

    },
```

Then I override bootstrap4 in AssetManager configuration:

```
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                 'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset' => [
                     'sourcePath' => null,
                     'basePath' => '@webroot',
                     'baseUrl' => '@web',
                     'css' => [
                         // override here
                         Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('theme') != 'dark' ?
                             (YII_ENV_DEV ? 'css/light/bootstrap.css' : 'css/light/bootstrap.min.css') :
                             (YII_ENV_DEV ? 'css/dark/bootstrap.css' : 'css/dark/bootstrap.min.css')
                         ,
                     ],
                 ],
               
            ],
        ],
```

But i got error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getRequest() on null in /var/www/html/config/web.php:71 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/web/index.php(10): require() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/config/web.php on line 71
```

I think that I cannot access cookies directly in configuration.
Just a guess, in config/web.php, may be I need bootstraping such as `'bootstrap' => ['log'],` or defined a new global variable, or another suggestion You can give me.

Any help or suggestion is so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your `css` configuration in a function call, it should work.

I tried both ways, I get the `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getRequest() on null in /app/common/config/main.php:XX` exception if I try to use your code, but it works if I update it to the one below.

```php
'assetManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset' => [
            'sourcePath' => null,
            'basePath' => '@webroot',
            'baseUrl' => '@web',
            'css' => static function () {
                return [
                    // override here
                    Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('theme') != 'dark' ?
                        (YII_ENV_DEV ? 'css/light/bootstrap.css' : 'css/light/bootstrap.min.css') :
                        (YII_ENV_DEV ? 'css/dark/bootstrap.css' : 'css/dark/bootstrap.min.css')
                    ,
                ];
            },
        ],
     ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'components' => [
    // code...
    'assetManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset' => [
                'sourcePath' => null,
                'basePath' => '@webroot',
                'baseUrl' => '@web',
            ],
         ],
    ],
    // code...
],

 // code...
'on beforeRequest' => function ($event) {
    \Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\\bootstrap4\\BootstrapAsset'] = [
        'css' => [
                 // override here
                 Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('theme') != 'dark' ?
                     (YII_ENV_DEV ? 'css/light/bootstrap.css' : 'css/light/bootstrap.min.css') :
                     (YII_ENV_DEV ? 'css/dark/bootstrap.css' : 'css/dark/bootstrap.min.css'),
             ],
     ];
},

'on beforeAction' => function ($event) {

    // default theme is 'light'
    if(!Yii::$app->request->cookies->has('theme')){
        Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new Cookie([
            'name' => 'theme',
            'value' => 'light',
        ]));
    }

},
```

- Please note that the server has nothing to do with cookies. The browser is responsible for doing the job. (As a result of the request)
  Therefore, cookie changes are not visible until the next page reload (next request).